# How to optimize memory in an algorithm

Tags: javascript, string, algorithm, memory

How can I optimize this

if the string can be split without a 4, 422 and 2222 without a remainder, returns true

tests:

- input "4" output "true"(4)
- input "44" output "true" (4 4)
- input "42" output false(4 2!==2222 || 422 || 4)
- input "4224224" output true (422 422 4)
- input "42222" output true (4 2222)
- input "22224"output true (2222 4)

```js
let solution = (password) => {
  if (!password) return false

  while (password) {

    if (password.includes('2222')) {
      while (password.includes('2222')) {
        password = password.replace('2222', '')
      }
    }
    if (password.includes('422')) {
      while (password.includes('422')) {
        password = password.replace('422', '')
      }
    }
    if (password.includes('4')) {
      while (password.includes('4')) {
        password = password.replace('4', '')
      }
    }
    return !!!password
  }
}

console.log(solution('4'));
console.log(solution('44'));
console.log(solution('42'));
console.log(solution('4224224'));
console.log(solution('42222'));
console.log(solution('22224'));
```

this is the same:

```js
let solution = (password) => {
  const searchValue = ['2222', '422', '4']
  if (!password) return false
  for (let elem = 0, i = searchValue[0]; password; elem++) {
    if (password.includes(i)) {
      while (password.includes(i)) {
        password = password.replace(i, '')
      }
    }
    i = searchValue[elem]
    if (elem === 3) {
      return !!!password
    }
  }
  return !!!password
}

console.log(solution('4'));
console.log(solution('44'));
console.log(solution('42'));
console.log(solution('4224224'));
console.log(solution('42222'));
console.log(solution('22224'));
```

Memory limitation on startup - 100 MB

- must work with -> `const bigStr = new Array(9999999).fill(() =>["4", "422", "2222" ][Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)]).map(f => f()).join('')`
- Sorry, I forgot to mention that regular expressions are not allowed use

Comment: What's the actual problem? You have 100 MB and this code needs much less memory. Why `!!!password`?

Comment: return !Boolean. (password) can be equal to a string of 999999 elements

Comment: I know `!password` and `!!password` but `!!!password` doesn't make any sense especially when you want to optimize. It adds two unnecessary operations. `!password === !!!password`

Comment: I've updated my solution. Have a look. Is  this what you want?

Comment: The space complexity of your code is linear `O(n)` and that's just because you store the input string in a variable. Otherwise the complexity would be constant `O(1)`. You need `2 * password.length + O(1)` memory. You can't really optimize it with JavaScript. Strings are immutable. You need two variables with the input strings to modify the string. 2 * 999999 characters are 2 * 999999 bytes  < 2 MB. That's still not too much. Even with 4 bytes per character (UTF8) it's still < 8 MB.

Comment: must work with -> const bigStr = new Array(9999999).fill(() =>["4", "422", "2222" ][Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)]).map(f => f()).join('')

Comment: Is the `searchValue` always `['2222', '422', '4']`, or is that just an example?

Comment: @user3386109 always

Answer (score 1):

**1)** You can get the desired result with recursion

```js
const matches = ["4", "2222", "422"];

function isMatch(str) {
  if (str.trim() === "") return true;

  for (let i = 0; i < matches.length; ++i) {
    if (str.startsWith(matches[i])) {
      if (isMatch(str.replace(matches[i], ""))) return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
console.log(isMatch("4"));
console.log(isMatch("44"));
console.log(isMatch("42"));
console.log(isMatch("4224224"));
console.log(isMatch("42222 "));
console.log(isMatch("2222"));
```

**2)** You can use regex here `\b(4|2222|422)+\b`

[image]

```js
const regex = /\b(4|2222|422)+\b/;

function isMatch(str) {
  return regex.test(str);
}
console.log(isMatch("4"));
console.log(isMatch("44"));
console.log(isMatch("42"));
console.log(isMatch("4224224"));
console.log(isMatch("42222 "));
console.log(isMatch("2222"));
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that regular expressions are not allowed use

Comment: @Nick But why is that so, Regex is one of the best ways to search in a string.

Comment: they're good. but those are the conditions of the problem.

Comment: A recursion has a much higher memory usage. You are creating a copy of the input string for each function call. This can exceed the memory limit after the second recursion step.

Comment: AFAIK, But `100MB` is enough to run similar test cases.

Comment: OP wants to optimize memory usage so your solution is to waste more memory? Your recursive approach can exceed the memory limit after 26 recursion steps. I had a bug in my previous calculation. One string can be 999999 * 4 bytes. You need two strings per modification. That's 999999 * 4 * 2. In each function call you have a copy of that string. That's also 999999 * 4. 999999 * 4 bytes is about 4 MB. I upvoted your answer for the regex but I'm not a fan of the recursive approach.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use [`replaceAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll) instead of replacing the string each time and check if it is in there another time:

```js
const bigStr = new Array(9999999).fill(() => ["4", "422", "2222"][Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)]).map(f => f()).join('');

const solution = (password) => {
  return password !== "" && !password.replaceAll('2222', '').replaceAll('422', '').replaceAll('4', '');
}

console.log(solution("4"));
console.log(solution("44"));
console.log(solution("42"));
console.log(solution("4224224"));
console.log(solution("42222"));
console.log(solution("2222"));
console.log(solution(bigStr))
```

Comment: Check this guys https://www.designcise.com/web/tutorial/how-to-fix-replaceall-is-not-a-function-javascript-error